# how to send an object to angular directive on a check-box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, icheck

i am trying to consume iCheck check box using a directive. my directive is setup like this.

```
    .module('app').directive('bootstrapCheck', ['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        compile: function (element, $attrs) {
            var icheckOptions = {
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
                radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
            };

            var modelAccessor = $parse($attrs['ngModel']);
            return function ($scope, element, $attrs, controller) {

                var modelChanged = function (event) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        modelAccessor.assign($scope, event.target.checked);
                    });
                };

                $scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function (val) {
                    var action = val ? 'check' : 'uncheck';
                    element.iCheck(icheckOptions, action).on('ifChanged', modelChanged);
                });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

my check-boxes are in ng-repeat. i want to send the current object to function to process it further. my html is setup like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="onChangeEvent(item)" bootstrap-check>
```

modelChanged gets triggered each time i change any check-box. but i am trying to access item inside modelChanged function to process it further. please guide.

Comment: Where do you want to access the `item`?

Comment: it looks like there is no way to call a $scope function on ng-change or ng-click since it is a plugin and has its own complexities so i am trying to access item inside directive modelChanged function.

Comment: You can call $scope function  on ng-change or ng-click.

Comment: thats true in the case of normal checkbox. but since this is a plugin (iCheck) its not calling ng-change or ng-click without a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `item` to directive scope and access it inside the `link` function. Along with `item` you can also pass the onChangeEvent handler to the directive. Try this.

JS

```
angular.module('app').directive('bootstrapCheck', ['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
        return {
            scope: {
               item: '=',
               onChangeEvent: '&'
            },
            compile: function (element, $attrs) {
                var icheckOptions = {
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
                };

                var modelAccessor = $parse($attrs['ngModel']);
                return function ($scope, element, $attrs, controller) {

                    var modelChanged = function (event) {

 //Here $scope.item will give you the item
 //This will trigger the parent controller's onChangeEvent set in the directive markup
 $scope.onChangeEvent({ item: $scope.item });

                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            modelAccessor.assign($scope, event.target.checked);
                        });
                    };

                    $scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function (val) {
                        var action = val ? 'check' : 'uncheck';
                        element.iCheck(icheckOptions, action).on('ifChanged', modelChanged);
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="item.isSelected" 
       item="item" 
       on-change-event="onChangeEvent(item)" bootstrap-check>
```

Comment: perfect. you are a gem.